# Why can't get $_SESSION data in a different directory (memcache)?

Tags: php

What server setting on my live server could be stopping me from seeing session data in a different directory on the same domain:

For example:

`dev.myhome.com/index.php`:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['foo'] = 'foo';
```

Navigating to `dev.myhome.com/subdir/testsession.php`:

```
session_start()
var_dump($_SESSION); // > array(0);
```

The PHPSESSID cookie is reported the same in developer tools:

```
NAME        DOMAIN          PATH    EXPIRES ON    VALUE                             HTTPONLY     SAMESITE
PHPSESSID   dev.myhome.com  /       Session       9e5297fa1577b4ea2096490ef3400cad  false         Unset
```

Comment: Check the actual request for `/subdir/testsession.php` in the network panel - does the cookie value get send back with that …?

Comment: Can you try this? `session_start();
$_SESSION['foo'] = $foo;`. And on the testsession.php do `session_start()
echo $foo = $_SESSION['foo'] ;`

Comment: So many possibilities... I'd start by checking if the session is written/saved correctly (check the file or whatever your session storage is).

Comment: @CBroe yes.. Cookie: PHPSESSID=9e5297fa1577b4ea2096490ef3400cad gets sent in the request.

Comment: With the exact same value? // Do you have full PHP error reporting enabled? No errors about headers already sent being suppressed when you try to start the session, stuff like that? Does calling this second script result in a new session cookie with a different value being set then?

Comment: @CBroe Same value. All error reporting is on. Second script doesn't create a new session cookie. Weird. I am on some silly strange hosting provider though (shared).

Comment: Do you have access to the session storage dir (assuming the normal PHP session handler that stores its data in files is used)? Check if a file corresponding to the session id was created, and if so, what it contains. If there’s no session files at all, then I’d first of all if PHP is allowed to write into that directory.

Comment: Doing an `echo session_save_path();` gives `tcp://AN_I_PADDRESS:11211?persistent=1&weight=1&timeout=1&retry_interval=15`